# Exclude an Item from an addelement

Tags: jquery, input

How can I exclude a certain input box from adding an element?

```
$('div#tabs input[type="text"], select option:selected, input:checked, textarea').addClass('takethis');
```

I wnat this for all input boxes and select boxes except for on certain input box. How would i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Traversing/not](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/not) or [Selectors/not](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/not):

```
$('div#tabs input[type="text"],
   select option:selected,
   input:checked, textarea').not('#elementToExclude').addClass('takethis');
```

Answer (score 0):

Two methods:

**CSS selector method**

First, give your special input an id:

`<input id="excluded-input" />`

Then, use the `:not` CSS selector to exclude it:

`$('[...], input:not(#excluded-input), [...]).addClass('takethis');`

**Traversal method**

Use the `.not()` function instead:

`$('div#tabs input[type="text"], select option:selected, input:checked, textarea').not('#excluded-input').addClass('takethis');`